# Strategy to forking and syncing a git repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-fork

In the context of my question, I have a fork  `origin\master` branch from `upstream\master` branch of a certain project.

My `origin` project is a completely stand alone project, which have new features, and I would never want to create a pull request to `upstream\master`. However, I want to get updates from `upstream\master` and stay synced to it.

In this scenario, `origin\master` is the `master` branch of my project, so it's supposed to be the most stable branch, and I would like to protect it, and restrict push operations to it. ([restricted branches](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.9/user/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/))

But if I understand it right, If I want to sync with `upstream\master`, I'm getting the changes to a local `master` branch of my project, and after resolving conflicts I need to push it to `origin\master`, which is a restricted branch - so I can't actually do that. In addition, I can't create a pull request from local `master` to `origin\master` due to the same restriction..

More generally speaking, intuitively it doesn't feel right to me to merge from `upstream\master` directly to `origin\master`.

Does anyone know if there is a better strategy for a scenario like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your local `master` branch is the working copy of `origin/master`, so you need to sync local `master` with `origin/master`. And it’s not make sense to sync `origin/master` with `upstream/master` directly.

If your `origin/master` branch protected not pushing to remote directly, you can **create another branch and push it to remote, then create a pull request to merge it into `master`**. Details as below:

```
#After you update local master to sync with upstream/master
git checkout -b temp
git push -u origin temp
```

In the github web page -> create a pull request -> merge `temp` branch into `master` -> finally the `origin/master` will has the update in `upstream/master` branch.

To sync local `master` branch with `origin/master`:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```